# Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 71.1605.0 and Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime 1.0.0.3 compatibility issue

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, android-workmanager

I have a Xamarin Forms v4.4.0.991640 (iOS & Android) solution which contains (among others) 2 projects:

1. ProjectAuth uses Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 71.1605.0 (currently the latest version)
2. ProjectWorker uses Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime 1.0.0.3 (again the latest version)

The names of the projects are not the actual ones btw.

It seems than when building the solution I get the following conflict:

```
Error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 directly to project ProjectWorker to resolve this issue. 
 ProjectWorker -> Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime 1.0.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Arch.Persistence.Room.Runtime 1.1.1.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils 28.0.0.3 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 28.0.0.3) 
 ProjectWorker -> AnotherProjectUsedByProjectWorker -> ProjectAuth -> Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 71.1605.0 -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement 71.1620.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 28.0.0.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 28.0.0.1). (NU1107)
```

**Solution 1**

The advice of installing Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 directly to project ProjectWorker failed with the same error as above.

**Solution 2**

Downgrading Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime didnt work again. There is only version 1.0.0.0.

**Solution 3**

I removed AnotherProjectUsedByProjectWorker's reference to ProjectAuth in order to break the chain ProjectWorker -> AnotherProjectUsedByProjectWorker -> ProjectAuth. This though is causing the following error when trying to build the Android project:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;
```

Is the issue related to the Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat versions used by Xamarin.Firebase.Auth and Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime respectively? Is the only solution waiting for a Xamarin.Firebase.Auth update (latest update was 9 months ago) or does anyone know any other workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have problem when you try to install Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 71.1605.0 and Xamarin.Android.Arch.Work.Runtime 1.0.0.3 in Xamarin.forms project? And the Xamarin.Forms version is v4.4.0.991640? Because these two library is for Android, and try to **set Android project target framework as Android 9.0**, then you can install these in android project successfully.

Comment: Thanks @CherryBu-MSFT. I raised it in the github repo and it seems that its a known issue and they are working on it. https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/333

Answer (score 0):

I also did have this problem the try install the NuGets  --> `Xamarin.Android.Arch.*`

My project is a few old, and after of migrate el project, I had to install the nutget  --> `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`

After of install Nutget I could already install the nutgets `Xamarin.Android.Arch.*`